# PHP string does not contain

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is to display a message (1) if the current link does not contain the words "index" or "/?"

I found this to do the direct opposite:

```
$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($page, 'index.php') !== false xor strpos($page, '/?') !== false) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '2';
}
```

This code displays "2" on pages where there is no "index" or "/?" in the link, but I need the opposite: display "1" where there is no "index" or  "/?" in the link.

BTW I have tried all combinations: !strpos, TRUE, !==, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I need a way without the "else" in the code, otherwise I could just change up the echos.

Comment: The boolean comparision `xor` is supposed to do so.

Comment: try ===false || ===false { one or both missing }

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($page, 'index.php') === false && strpos($page, '/?') === false) 
{
    echo"1";
}
else
{
    echo"2";
}
```

Should display `1` if there's no `index.php` or `/?` in `$page`

Comment: @stu worked perfectly. How do I know when to use xor, || or &&? && was the only one I didn't try and this was the solution lol. Thanks man. BTW why does it work with AND if only one of the two is true?

Comment: @Waygood I assumed the url would be `/index.php` or `/?` not contain both, so if the url is `/index.php` then `strpos($page, '/?')` would return false, and 1 would be returned, if the url is `/?` then `strpos($page, 'index.php')` would return false, and 1 would be returned, if the url contained neither of them, both statements would return false and 1 would be returned, so if you use *OR*, the code would always return 1 unless the url was `index.php/?`?

Comment: xor = "one or the other but not both".

Comment: to assume to to make an ASS out of U and ME

Comment: @Waygood lol :) np 10now, one of many solutions as you can see from other answers

Comment: +1 I personally prefer `stristr();` instead of `strpos();` as there's no ===false to worry about

Comment: @Waygood good point, there are indeed many ways to skin a cat! :)

Comment: @Waygood This is just De Morgan's Law to the original condition.

Comment: @Waygood !(a || b) == !a && !b - that's one of the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), so Stu is absolutely right.

Comment: I have no idea, but this is the only way it works for me :). Best answer.

Comment: This solution is invalid. It will print 1 only when both cases are missing. There’s a difference between logical and and logical or. OP specifically asked for the OR thus the solution does not provide a valid answer.

Comment: @emix you are correct, however I think there's a translation between what was asked and what is needed: "I need the opposite: display "1" where there is no "index" or "/?" in the link."

Taken as:

I need to display "1" where there is no "index" and where there is no "/?" in the link

The above returns "1" when neither "index" nor "/?" exist in the string. i.e. neither are present, which I think is what OP was after.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your if statement is

```
if( <<COND 1>> xor <<COND 2>> )
```

where, `xor`'s feature is

> return **`TRUE`** if either `<<COND 1>>` or `<<COND 2>>` is **`TRUE`**, but not both.

You should instead use this:

```
if( strpos($page, 'index.php') !== false OR strpos($page, '/?') !== false )
```

---

Check this page for more information about [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: +1 for the explanation of XOR and also for the comment above regarding the De Morgan's law ;-)

Comment: yeah but I need a solution without else. Your solutions says the opposite: "if index is in the link do this". I need "if index is not in the link do this".

Answer (score 2):

```
$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($page, '/?') === false && strpos($page, 'index.php') === false) 
{
  echo "1";
}
else
{
  echo "2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($page, 'index.php') === false || strpos($page, '/?') === false) 

{

echo"1";

}

else

{

echo"2";

}
```